# Axis2 Connection reset on read after successful write to the wire

Tags: java, apache-axis

I googled a lot and did a lot of research yet couldnt find a solution and hence writing here.

1. There are no firewall issues
2. No network issues

We are using Axis2 to make SOAP calls to a 3rd party server. However intermittently we see Connection errors. I enabled httpclient loggers and see that write to the wire was successfully done, however, issue is coming when the server is trying to do a read. The issue comes intermittantly, however every time it comes it always comes during the read. Below are the log stmts.

```
 [DefaultHttpParams] (t-4403) Set parameter http.connection-manager.timeout = 30000
 [DefaultHttpParams] (t-4403) Set parameter http.connection.timeout = 60000
 [DefaultHttpParams] (t-4403) Set parameter http.socket.timeout = 60000
 [DefaultHttpParams] (t-4403) Set parameter http.socket.timeout = 60000
...
...
        1014433413 04-01 09:20:34 DEBUG [HttpConnection] (t-4403) enter HttpConnection.write(byte[], int, int)
    1014433413 04-01 09:20:34 DEBUG [EntityEnclosingMethod] (t-4403) enter EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(HttpState, HttpConnection)
    1014433413 04-01 09:20:34 DEBUG [PostMethod] (t-4403) enter PostMethod.hasRequestContent()
    1014433413 04-01 09:20:34 DEBUG [EntityEnclosingMethod] (t-4403) enter EntityEnclosingMethod.hasRequestContent()
    1014433413 04-01 09:20:34 DEBUG [EntityEnclosingMethod] (t-4403) enter EntityEnclosingMethod.getRequestContentLength()
    1014433413 04-01 09:20:34 DEBUG [PostMethod] (t-4403) enter PostMethod.hasRequestContent()
    1014433413 04-01 09:20:34 DEBUG [EntityEnclosingMethod] (t-4403) enter EntityEnclosingMethod.hasRequestContent()
    1014433413 04-01 09:20:34 DEBUG [HttpConnection] (t-4403) enter HttpConnection.getRequestOutputStream()
    1014433413 04-01 09:20:34 DEBUG [EntityEnclosingMethod] (t-4403) Request body sent
    1014433413 04-01 09:20:34 DEBUG [HttpConnection] (t-4403) enter HttpConnection.flushRequestOutputStream()
    1014433413 04-01 09:20:34 DEBUG [HttpMethodBase] (t-4403) enter HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpState, HttpConnection)
    1014433413 04-01 09:20:34 DEBUG [HttpMethodBase] (t-4403) enter HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpState, HttpConnection)
    1014433413 04-01 09:20:34 DEBUG [HttpConnection] (t-4403) enter HttpConnection.readLine()
    1014433413 04-01 09:20:34 DEBUG [HttpParser] (t-4403) enter HttpParser.readLine(InputStream, String)
    1014433413 04-01 09:20:34 DEBUG [HttpParser] (t-4403) enter HttpParser.readRawLine()
    1014433413 04-01 09:20:34 DEBUG [HttpMethodDirector] (t-4403) Closing the connection.
    1014433413 04-01 09:20:34 DEBUG [HttpConnection] (t-4403) enter HttpConnection.close()
    1014433413 04-01 09:20:34 DEBUG [HttpConnection] (t-4403) enter HttpConnection.closeSockedAndStreams()
    1014433413 04-01 09:20:34 DEBUG [HttpMethodDirector] (t-4403) Method retry handler returned false. Automatic recovery will not be attempted
    1014433413 04-01 09:20:34 DEBUG [HttpConnection] (t-4403) enter HttpConnection.releaseConnection()
    1014433413 04-01 09:20:34 DEBUG [HttpConnection] (t-4403) Releasing connection back to connection manager.
    1014433413 04-01 09:20:34 TRACE [MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager] (t-4403) enter HttpConnectionManager.releaseConnection(HttpConnection)
    1014433413 04-01 09:20:34 DEBUG [MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager] (t-4403) Freeing connection, hostConfig=HostConfiguration[host=https://c.ap2.visual.force.com]
    1014433413 04-01 09:20:34 TRACE [MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager] (t-4403) enter HttpConnectionManager.ConnectionPool.getHostPool(HostConfiguration)
    1014433413 04-01 09:20:34 DEBUG [IdleConnectionHandler] (t-4403) Adding connection at: 1459502434809
    1014433413 04-01 09:20:34 DEBUG [MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager] (t-4403) Notifying no-one, there are no waiting threads
    1014433413 04-01 09:20:34 INFO  [HTTPSender] (t-4403) Unable to sendViaPost to url[https://c.ap2.visual.force.com/services/Soap/u/35.0/0099900JK2x]
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
            at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
            at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
            at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
            at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
            at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
```

Observe the writes & flush both happen successfully. Only when the read happens the error comes. Below are the jars in classpath

```
    axis-1.4.jar
    axis2-adb-1.5.6.jar
    axis2-codegen-1.5.6.jar
    axis2-kernel-1.5.6.jar
    axis2-transport-http-1.5.6.jar
    axis2-transport-local-1.5.6.jar
    axis2-xmlbeans-1.5.6.jar
 httpclient-4.3.6.jar
 httpcore-4.3.3.jar
```

Any help? or pointers?

Answer (score 0):

OK i did the below and the issue is not reproducable on multiple testings.

```
Options options = stub._getServiceClient().getOptions();
    options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.CHUNKED, Boolean.FALSE);
    options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.REUSE_HTTP_CLIENT, Boolean.FALSE);
    options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.AUTO_RELEASE_CONNECTION , Boolean.TRUE);
    options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.HTTP_PROTOCOL_VERSION,HTTPConstants.HEADER_PROTOCOL_10);
```

Just incase some body else is looking for an answer!